# How to find the actual close reason for a question?

Tags: support, data-explorer

After creating a query to figure out the close reason for a question at https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/edit/489136 I notice that the close reason type is listed multiple times.

To figure out the close reason I followed the https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/244032 documentation and more specifically the `PostHistory` table with `PostHistoryTypeId = 10`, yet I get two entries for the close reason type whereas I would expect only a single close reason.

Take https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128975/generating-a-balanced-binary-tree as example question, in my SEDE query it gets two entries, one with `CloseReasonType = 103` and the other with `CloseReasonType = 102`, both cast by user Jamal, meaning "Unclear what you're asking" and "Off-topic" respectively.

Now my question is: How do I figure out the close reason that is listed on the question? In the example question it is listed as "put on hold as off-topic by Jamal♦ 19 hours ago" and the mentioning of "Unclear what you're asking" is completely gone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the post's [timeline](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/128975/timeline), it has two close reasons because it's been closed twice.

It was first closed as unclear what you're asking then reopened and closed again as off-topic all by Jamal who as a site moderator can do that singlehandedly.

The close reason displayed on the post will be the one with the latest `CreationDate` entry where the `PostHistoryTypeId = 10` [Something like this perhaps](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/489166)

Answer (score -1):

When a question got 5 close votes it ist closed and the reason is shown below, but as long as there are not enough votes, you can savely use the *close* link. It will display a list of reasons first, why you "want" to close it too. You don't have to choose, but you see the pending reasons as a small number beneath each option.

[image]

Comment: The question asked about the close reason in the Data Explorer. The OP probably knows this dialog.